# Derivation using inference rules

Tags: logic

Suppose I have the premise:

> ~(AvB).(Negation A or B)

How can I get to the conclusion:

> A<=>B (A if and only if B)

using inference rules like introduction or elimination and also assumptions?

I need to set up a derivation with a scope line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's about half the proof you need:

```
1. ~(A v B)   Premise
2. | A        Assumption
3. | A v B    vI 2
4. | (A v B) & ~ (A v B) &I 3,1
5. ~A         Contradiction Elimination
6. ~A v B     vI 5
7. A -> B     Material Implication 6
...
~14. A <-> B   Biconditional Introduction 7, 13
```

---

Proof with DeMorgan:

```
1. ~(A v B)   Premise
2. ~A & ~B    DeM 1
3. ~A         &E 2
4. ~A v B     vI 3
5. A -> B     Material Implication 4
...
10. A <-> B Biconditional Introduction 5,9
```

Comment: Could you explain why your assumption was A?

Comment: Because we need to arrive at a contradiction to get out of the conditional proof?

Comment: Thank you. By the way in case you haven't noticed I am very new to this, that is why I am asking such basic questions. We all have to start somewhere right?

Comment: Can we use de-morgan to simplify ~A and ~B derivation? Can we then conclude that A=B? I mean can we switch to the semantic level saying that if premise requires both A = false and B =false, which means that their logic value is the same and thus propositions are equal?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov either of those approaches could work depending on the conditions under which one is asked to prove this. DeMorgan would eliminate the need for a conditional proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate proof using contradiction elimination (explosion):

[image]

The proof uses disjunction introduction (∨I), contradiction introduction (⊥I), contradiction elimination (⊥E) and biconditional introduction (↔I).

To help make this result intuitive, *¬(A ∨ B)* is true only when both *A* and *B* are false. But that is also a valuation that makes *A↔B* true.  When *¬(A ∨ B)* is false it does not matter what value *A↔B* has. The conditional representing the premise as antecedent and the conclusion as consequent will be true.

Links to the proof checker and descriptions of these inference rules can be found below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf